# jQuery Background Image flicker and Margin Woes

Tags: jquery, background-image, margin, flicker

I'm trying to try rebuilding my personal portfolio site from scratch, mostly for jQuery practice, and I've only just started but am having 2 problems.

First of all, here's a link to  a preview of what I have so far: http://www.forrestmckinney.com/portfolio-preview/

Basically my thinking was to have big background images with divs that scroll into view on every other navigation click.  As the divs scroll, the background image changes.  However, I also want the divs to be sized dynamically via the break_size function which is where I'm having the issue.  The function works great for setting the size of each div, even on resize, but for some reason the spacing is off.  The first one shows up fine, then each one after that is too high:

```
function break_size() {
    var windowY = $(window).height();   
    var breakHeight =(94 * windowY) / 100;

    var marginY = ((windowY - breakHeight)/2);

    $('.break').css('height', breakHeight);
    $('.break').css('margin-top', marginY + windowY);
    $('.break').css('margin-bottom', marginY);
}
```

So unless I'm missing something, this code should set the height of each .break div to 94% of the window hight, set the marginY variable to the (window height - break height)/2 (one half for top, one half for bottom), and then set the bottom margin to marginY and top margin to to the marginY plus the height of the window (effectively spacing out each div by one window height, allowing the full background image to show up in between divs).

The other issue I have is with the flicker in between images.  I've added e.preventDefaults(), but no luck.

Anyone know what's going on there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`var image_url = 'url(images/image1.jpg';`

Typo on line 15, missing parentheses.

Your math is accurate, but something isn't working with the css. The elements are not positioning correctly. It looks like the bottom margin of each element isn't effecting the one bellow it.
I couldn't find out why this is, but I found a workaround, add the bottom margin to the top of the other elements:

```
$('.break').css('height', breakHeight);
//remove bottom margin, use extra top margin instead
$('.break').css('margin-top', marginY + marginY + windowY); 
//normal margin for first child
$('.break:first-child').css('margin-top', marginY + windowY);
```

Theoretically this could work in your setup but I didn't test it.

As far as the flickering, I may also be wrong about this so let me know, but it looks like you are changing the background image anytime the buttons are pressed. Changing the background image alone is going to cause this but it also doesn't need to be changed everytime the button is clicked. You should instead stack the images and change visibility of the stacked images, that way they are preloaded. Then, only swap images when needed.